# Disable All Apache-Added Headers

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, configure

i have apache 2.2 and php 5.3.8 installed on my pc running windows 7, and i was trying to send http responses using the php. but i realized that apache automatically adds some headers like Date: and Server: in the response. is there any way to prevent this? i don't want any header to be added by apache.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you want standard headers such as `Date` to be omitted?!

Answer (score 3):

You can minimize the header output of Apache by setting the following two lines in you apache2.conf:

```
ServerTokens ProductOnly
ServerSignature Off
```

This will disable the servers signature. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serversignature

As for the Date header, this is required by the HTTP standard.

Comment: Anyway to achieve this with .htaccess?