# PHP Don't Let Apache Send Headers

Tags: php, apache

I have installed php + apache. From one php file i send some headers using the header() function.

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
header("Connection: Keep-Alive");
header("Content-Type: video/mp2t");
```

But i don't want apache to send its own headers. If i execute the PHP File i get these headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 15 Apr 2014 10:26:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u8
Connection: Keep-Alive, Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: video/mp2t
```

How can i prevent apache from sending its own headers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031315/disable-all-apache-added-headers

Comment: Yes but this will prevent sending headers like Transfer-Encoding / Connection etc? It isnt only for Server Banner?

Comment: Doesn't work, its only for the server banner

Comment: You should ask about the _specific_ header(s) that is causing you problems, show what you are doing, as well as indicate your obtained _and desired_ result. Sending a 200 explicitly is a bit weird.

Comment: The headers are important for browsers to interpret it correctly and not something you can strip out entirely, as per the answer I quoted. Why you want to mess with something that has absolutely no visible impact on your end user, only you would know